# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, file-read

I am getting array index out of bound error in MAP part. My code is as below. I am trying to read the input file from the HDFS. Is there any better way to read the HDFS file?

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
        {
                private Text key12 = new Text();
                private Text value = new Text();

                public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
                {
                        String line=value.toString();
                        while((line = value.toString()) != null)
                        {
                                        //StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
                                        //String field = tokenizer.nextToken();
                                        //
                                        String[] parts= line.split(" ");

                                        if(parts[0].contains("STN") == false)
                                        {
                                                String field=parts[0];
                                                String month=parts[3];
                                                String temp;
                                                if(parts[7].trim().equals(""))
                                                {
                                                        temp=parts[8];
                                                }
                                                else
                                                        temp=parts[7];
                                                //tokenizer.nextToken();
                                                //String month = tokenizer.nextToken();

                                                month=month.substring(4,6);
                                                //String temp = tokenizer.nextToken();

                                                String val = month+temp;

                                                key12.set(field);
                                                value.set(val);
                                                output.collect(key12, value);
                                        }
                        }
        }
```

Comment: can you paste same sample lines from your input and stacktrace that you see and which line it points in stack trace please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are an awful lot of places where this could go wrong, irrespective of where this particular error is. What if `parts` doesn't have 9 elements? What if it does have 9 elements but some of them are null? What if `line` doesn't have a space character in it? What if `month` only has three characters in it?

Handle all of these situations and your issue will be resolved.

As an aside, use

```
 if(!parts[0].contains("STN"))
```

instead of

```
 if(parts[0].contains("STN") == false)
```

and consider extracting some of your Strings (such as `"STN"` and `" "` into `private static final String` variables. This will greatly improve your performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help! i got the problem. I am reading the one line every time with this code. When it tries to read second line, it gets some garbage value. I am not able to read multiple line with this code. Can somebody help me in reading multiple line using this type of structure in map reduce. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is that representative of those lines in your raw data? i.e. is the second line also garbage?

Comment: nop. it's not reading second line as garbage. It's some random value. I want to read file line by line.